# Drupal 8 break apart page.content not working

Tags: drupal-8

Trying to utilize fields in a template and break apart page.content

The `{{ content.field_machine_name }}` does not work in my particular content type.

Is there something I am missing here? I read the documentation:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/using-custom-content-types-and-fields-with-twig

From my understanding you should be able to use `{{ content.whatever }}` and it display that particular field.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was looking in the wrong place.